# autoincrement alphanumeric values

Tags: php, sql

i want to autoincrement the alphanumeric characters
Ex:amp001,amp002,amp003
Can anyone plz help me in solving this problem.

i should get column like

```
id
abc001
abc002
abc003
abc004
..
..
..
```

Comment: If you are looking for native solution - then there's not. MySQL does not support sequences (unlike Oracle, for example). So you need to generate it in your application or use triggers.

Answer (score 2):

You can't auto increment alphanumeric values. Just Change the field type to numeric and set auto increment to that field. Concate your string value before the ID, while fetching the value. Eg: `<?php echo "abc".$row['id']; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this, use php's [uniqid](https://www.php.net/uniqid) function.

Answer (score 0):

Look this example

```
//connect to you database
//$count = mysql_query("select count(*) from table_name");
$id = "abc";
if (strlen($count+1) < 4)
{
    $count++;
    for($i=0;$i<(3 - strlen($count));$i++)
    {
        $id .='0';
    }
    $id .= $count;
}
```